# New tab open always even normal form form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, codeigniter

I'm using two submit buttons, one for page open in new tab (preview) and another for ordinary form submission (publish).

My issues are:

1. If I click preview button and open in tab, after that publish button click again NEW TAB will open
2. After refresh only publish button submit usually.

```html
<form method="post" name="form">
  Name : <br> <input type="text" name="name"/><br />
  Address : <br> <input type="text" name="address"/><br />
  <input name="publish" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="action='proccess.php?action=submit';"> 
  <input type="submit" value="preview" onclick='formpreview(this.form)'/>
</form>

<script>
  function formpreview(form) 
    form.target = '_blank';
    form.action = 'preview.php';
    form.submit();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can check button values, and then submit form with you conditions,

```
<form method="post" name="form">
  Name : <br> <input type="text" name="name"/><br />
  Address : <br> <input type="text" name="address"/><br />
  <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="formpreview(this.form,this)"> 
  <input type="submit" value="preview" onclick='formpreview(this.form,this)'/>
</form>

<script>
  function formpreview(form,btn) {
    alert(btn.value);
    /*form.target='_blank';
    form.action='preview.php';
    form.submit();*/
    if(btn.value=="preview"){
        alert(btn.value);
        form.target='_blank';
        form.action='preview.php';
        form.submit();
    }
    if(btn.value=="Submit"){
        alert(btn.value);
         form.target='_self';
         form.action='proccess.php?action=submit';
         form.submit();
    }

  }
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this one but its also have same issue ..plz try urself and help me .issue is when u click publish its work on same page but if you click preview button then its open new tab AND IF WE  AGAIN CLICK PUBLISH BUTTON IT Opens in  NEW TAB . that's the problem . i need two buttons works sepratlly

Comment: can you again check ? now i have edited my answer, checking target attribute

Comment: thanku sooo much ..itgs working ..i stuck with issue more than two days ..thanks a lot..

Answer (score 1):

**Remove**

```
form.target = '_blank';
```

`target="_blank"`  is given when you want to open webpages in new tab.

**Edit**

```
<form method="post" name="form" action="proccess.php?action=submit">
  Name : <br> <input type="text" name="name"/><br />
  Address : <br> <input type="text" name="address"/><br />
  <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="publish" > Publish </button>
  <button type="button" value="preview" onclick='formpreview(this.form)'>Preview</button
</form>
```

Comment: actually i want two buttons one for preview its open in new tab. and publish button click i need to normal submit. button when i click preview first ,then always open new tab while clicking publish

Comment: So instead of submit button, just use normal button.

Comment: create a separate submit button and a normal button call your function on normal button n let submit button do its work.

Comment: I tried that also use two button but same issues going on @kishor10d

Comment: @shyamprasad i have made some edit in my answer check it out